# sharing cookies between rails 3 and rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4, base64

I am trying to have shared cookies between Rails 3 and Rails 4.1 apps. The problem is that the Rails 3 cookies are just base64 encoded, but the Rails 4.1 cookies are encrypted.

Is there any way to make both Rails 3 and Rails 4.1 make to use compatible cookies?

For now the most easy way seems to downgrade to Rails 4.0

Comment: I believe there's no back port of Rails 4 cookie mechanism to Rails 3. Why not an upgrade?

Answer (score 7):

To get this working unset `secret_key_base` and instead use the same `secret_token` that you use in your Rails 3 app. Then the trick is to also set `action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :marshal`. Otherwise Rails 4 stored the cookie in a format Rails 3 cannot read.

So my final config/initializers/session_store.rb has

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :marshal
Rails.application.config.secret_token = 'verylongstring'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unsetting `secret_key_base` and setting `secret_token` to the same value you're using in your Rails 3 app? This might not work, but I don't see anything in the 4.1 upgrade guide to suggest it wouldn't.

If that doesn't work, the options I can think of:

1. Switch to a different session store (Memcached, ActiveRecord, whatever). Not ideal, since it means more infrastructure, but it should work.
2. Write your own cookie middleware. If you **really** need to share cookie information between multiple applications, this is your best long term solution. Don't depend on the pre-built Rails stuff, since (as you've found) that's hard to keep in sync. Write your own Rack middleware that's portable and does exactly what you need.

Comment: I tried have the same secret_key_base and secret_token but it did not work.

We end up with own cookie middleware, as you mentioned.